# How do I read .txt files with fstream in c++

Tags: c++, qt-creator, fstream, ifstream

I have to write a c++ programm with QtCreator to evaluate a football table. The results of every game is saved in a text file ("Bundesliga.txt"). We have to use fstream to read the file, but I can't open it.
Here is my test programm to read the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char test[10];
    ifstream table;
    table.open("Bundesliga.txt");
    if (table.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error Opening File \n";
        exit(1);
    }

    table.getline(test, 10);
    cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

The textfile is saved in the project folder and I imported the file as RESOURCES and OTHER_FILES. Nothing worked. I'm glad for evey single help!

## Edit:

I'm using Qt-Creator.

Comment: Try supplying full path instead of relative one

Comment: Or you can try to create new file (using ofstream), check where it been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the following:

1. The `.txt` file must be within the source code file's folder.
2. Check that your file name as you see it in the folder isn't `Bundesliaga.txt`, it's interpreted to `Bundesliga.txt.txt`. This is a common mistake.
3. Ask `if(!table.is_open())`
4. You're not nulling the string with `\0`. Do that or use `table >> setw(10)`. setw is declared at  `<iomanip>` and nulls the string with `\0`.

Comment: Speaking about nulling the string, you forget about avoiding buffer overflow. If you read 10 chars into an array of 10, and then append a null, you'll overflow the array.